# Why does a div with background-color show fixed elements below?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create some static content using a `div` with `position: fixed` and then allow a solid `div` with a `background-color` to scroll over it and hide the static text below.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="static-background">
        <p>Why can I see this through the yellow div?</p>
        <p> <a href="#">this should be clickable</a>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.static-background {
    position: fixed;
}
.overlay {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200%;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

But the yellow `div` just shows the text through from the fixed background.

Why is this?

By setting `z-index: -1;` in `.static-background` i get the desired behaviour, **except** that the link is no longer clickable and the text is not selectable.

How do I make the background of `.overlay` hide the fixed elements behind while still allowing interaction (until hidden)?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zelanix/mcdbopj6/1/).

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.static-background {
  position: fixed;
}
.overlay {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200%;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="static-background">
    <p>Why can I see this through the yellow div?</p>
    <p> <a href="#">this should be clickable</a>

    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mcdbopj6/2/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you give the element `.static-background` a negative `z-index`, it is being placed behind the parent `.container` element, which is why the element is unclickable.

To work arond this, you need to give the parent element, `.container`, a `z-index` to [establish a stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) between the elements.

In this case, you can simply give it a `z-index` of `1`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ybfa7esa/)

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;      /* Added */
}
```

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.static-background {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}
.overlay {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200%;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="static-background">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p><a href="#">this should be clickable</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

As an alternative, you could also just give the element `.overlay` a `z-index` of `1`, and remove the `z-index`s from the other elements. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLj6r039/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - it was the `z-index` on the container that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add some z-index to your elements:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.static-background {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:  99;
}
.overlay {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200%;
    margin-top: 200px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your css to this...

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.static-background {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:4;
}
.overlay {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200%;
    margin-top: 200px;
    z-index:5;
    position:relative;
}
```

Working JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DivakarDass/mcdbopj6/3/